# 2-norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have come across the 2-norm of a matrix, http://www.matrixanalysis.com/Page281.pdf, this is something I found on the web. In particular, MATLAB calculates a norm of a matrix via the 2-norm, I was hoping if someone could give a more easier way to find a 2 norm of any matrix (any example), as I presume working out the eigenvalues for a 2 norm is a fairly long route surely?

Thanks

Comment: Not really, except in special cases.

Comment: You need only to compute/estimate certain *largest* eigenvalue. This is usually quite an "easy" task.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel right ok yh in some cases this is easy i guess

Comment: There is also the $1$-norm and $\infty$-norm.  These are much easier to compute.  (There is also a $p$-norm for any $1 \le p \le \infty$, but in the cases where $p$ is neither $1$, $2$, nor $\infty$, this is much harder.)